# c# how to draw line chart

Tags: c#, charts, linechart

I am trying to create line chart to display the data. Currently I have the code to display bar chart. Here it is

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

private void CreateChart()
{
    var series = new Series("Finance");

    // Frist parameter is X-Axis and Second is Collection of Y- Axis
    series.Points.DataBindXY(new[] { 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004 }, new[] { 100, 200, 90, 150 });
    chart1.Series.Add(series);

}
```

It works perfectly fine. How could I modify this to display line chart ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [`ChartType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.charttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) propetry of the series to [`Line`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```